# Problem with different query loops (and "main loop") on category template page!

Tags: categories, loop, query-posts, page-template, wp-reset-query

so, heres the problem:

i've created a category-template (category.php) with two query loops and the main loop (in which the content from the category should get looped in). if i now click on a category the template page shows but also the first two query loops get affected by it. everything is messed up.

above is my template architecture. as you can see, i used the wp_reset_query function but this did not help. how do i make JUST THE MAIN LOOP react to the catgeory posts?

**the first loop:**

```
<div id="slider1">
 <?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'slider');
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();?>
    <div class="startslide" style="background-color: <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Farbcode', true); ?>">
        <div class="slideimg"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'slider' ); ?></div>
        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        <div class="subline"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
    </div>
 <?php endwhile; ?>
 <?php wp_reset_query(); ?> 

</div> <!--! end of #slider1 -->
```

**the second loop:**

```
<div id="topteaser">
<?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'teaser');
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();?>
        <div class="topteaseritem" style="background:url(<?php $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), array( 36,36 ), false, '' ); echo $src[0]; ?>) no-repeat 10px top">
            <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div>
       <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php wp_reset_query(); ?> 
</div>
```

**..and the third loop (the main loop):**

```
<div id="slider2">
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <div class="post">
        <div class="postimg"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'related' ); ?> </a></div>
        <div class="postcontent">
            <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div> <!--! end of #slider2 -->
```

i hope you get my problem as i'm not a native english speaker (it's hard to explain all that) ;-)

Comment: 'but also the first two query loops get affected by it. everything is messed up.' - what does that mean? can you describe in more detail what happens in the first two loops, and what exactly 'the mess' is?

Comment: ok sorry, "messed up" menas: in the way how i did it the third loop shows all the posts from the right category (how i want it to be).. but the other first two loops do the same which they shouldn't?!?! summarized said: all three loops get affected by the catgeory-page but i want only the third loop to be affected (the other two should loop the posts from the categories which i defined by the query-codes)!

Answer (score 2):

In order to provide more-specific help, we'll need to know greater detail regarding exactly what's happening that you don't expect, or what's not happening that you expect to happen, or what is happening differently from what you expect.

That said, there are at least two things that will likely help you:

1. Use descriptive and *unique* variable names to hold your custom queries
2. Include the **`if ( have_posts() )`** part of the Loop
3. Call `wp_reset_postdata()` instead of `wp_reset_query()`

### Variable Names

You use the generic variable `$arg` to hold your custom query arguments, and the generic variable `$loop` to hold both of your custom queries. Instead, I would suggest:

```
$slider_query_args = array( 'post_type' => 'slider');
$slider_query = new WP_Query( $slider_query_args );
```

...and...

```
$teaser_query_args = array( 'post_type' => 'teaser');
$teaser_query = new WP_Query( $teaser_query_args );
```

Doing this makes your code easier to read/follow, helps ensure that you don't mix the two custom queries, and helps avoid unintended consequences in the two custom query calls.

### Full Loop Call

You use:

```
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
```

Instead, use:

```
if ( $slider_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $slider_query->have_posts() ) : $slider_query->the_post();
    // Loop output
endwhile; endif;
```

...and...

```
if ( $teaser_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $teaser_query->have_posts() ) : $teaser_query->the_post();
    // Loop output
endwhile; endif;
```

### Reset Post Data after Custom Queries

**Note: This one may very likely be your main problem.**

The [**`wp_reset_query()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query) function is intended to reset the **main query** after it has been altered (e.g. via `query_posts()`). Since you're not altering the main query, calling `wp_reset_query()` isn't going to do anything for you.

Instead, use **[`wp_reset_postdata()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata)**, which is intended to reset the `$post` global variable, and all the related template tags (e.g. `the_title()`, `the_content()`, `the_permalink()`, etc.) to refer once again to the main query. Since you're calling `the_post()` in your custom query loops, you'll want to use `wp_reset_postdata()`:

```
// Slider Loop
if ( $slider_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $slider_query->have_posts() ) : $slider_query->the_post();
    // Loop output
endwhile; endif;
// Rest postdata
wp_reset_postdata();

// Teaser Loop
if ( $teaser_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $teaser_query->have_posts() ) : $teaser_query->the_post();
    // Loop output
endwhile; endif;
// Rest postdata
wp_reset_postdata();

// Main Query Loop
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ): the_post();
    // Loop output
endwhile; endif;
```

Comment: thanks for you detailed answer but that does not work at all – it shows a blank page. the main problem is (which i apparently did not make that clear): in the way how i did it the third loop shows all the posts from the right category fine.. but the other firts two loops do the same which they shouldn't?!?!

Comment: If you got a blank page, what **fatal error** did you get?

Comment: nothing.. just a blank page?!?

Comment: A blank page generally means a fatal error somewhere. Ensure that `WP_DEBUG` is enabled, so that you can see error messages.

Comment: I don't quite get why this answer did not receive a single upvote (now it did), but there is one piece of misinformation in there. While `wp_reset_query` certainly is not a necessary call, if the main query hasn't been altered, it does not only reset the `$wp_query` global but in turn also calls `wp_reset_postdata`. So using the former will also end up resetting the `$post` global. See http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/query.php#L94